# I'm trying to hide JUST the header on a few pages on my Wix site. There seems to be no way to do this. Ideas?

Tags: javascript, header, velo

I'm attempting to hide JUST the header on a few pages on my Wix site. There literally seems to be no way to do this.

Here's what I've already tried (to no avail).

1. Checking the "Hide Header and Footer" radio button

This hides the header, footer AND menu on the page. Def not what I want.

2. Using JS to hide an element on a certain page as seen here:
   https://support.wix.com/en/article/how-to-hide-an-element-on-certain-pages

Again, this works fine for individual elements but doesn't work on the header.

3. I also tried hiding both the Header and Footer with the intention to recreate the footer separately. The BIG problem with this is - that option also hides the menu...curiouser and curiouser!

I'm quite at a loss at why Wix tied all 3 elements; header + footer + menu to each other to make it so that they all show or do not show on the page.

Such a basic function that should have been taken care of ages ago. Anyway, maybe I missed something? Is anyone else facing this issue? I'm open to any and all ideas :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1 & 2 seem to indeed be the case, but I don't think you are correct on 3. If the menu is not attached to the head and is not set to show on all pages, when you hide the header and footer the menu should still display. You can add the menu to each page manually and make sure it is not set to show on all pages. Not ideal, but it should work.

Comment: Thanks, Sam! Appreciate your response. I agree, #3 seems super cumbersome. I think I'll have to stick with having a header on every single page until Wix decides to throw us a bone.